# Never mind... Just go AFAYC

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

```
n O . h t h D i c e
X y Z h O i r o n .
p s a Y B w o r d k
i T . G r O W I T n
m Z B L e e I . i i
E i u A w I T m m r
a l a S i s H a i d
n a S H R I n K K I
L e r O u M E P e A
l . i p I z z l R .
```

"Here, solve it."

"But... I don't know where to start, nor where I'm heading to."

"Never mind... Just go as far as you can, and as fast as you can."

"Well... May I ask for further hints?"

"NO, THIS IS NOT ALLOWED!"

---

Above is the original question.
Below are hints.

---

Hint 1:

> One crucial tag is omitted in purpose (could be added later as further hint).

---

Hint 2:

> *Far = Longest*
>
>  *Fast = Shortest*
>
>
>  ... What!?

---

Hint 3:

> Two numbers are involved: $1$ and $\sqrt{2}$.

---

Hint 4:

> @OmegaKrypton mentioned this in the comment.
>
>  The `chess` tag is again not the correct tag, but could be very weakly relevant.
>
>  The `knight move`, however, is totally irrelevant, since it only involves one number: $\sqrt{5}$.

---

Hint 5:

> The most important hint so far is Hint 0.

---

Hint 6:

> The missing tag is `mazes`.
>
>  To keep it as a hint, I don't add it to the tags.

---

Hint 7:

> What are the "walls" of the maze?
>
>  It's given in Hint 0...

Comment: *Asks for hints*

Comment: @Avi First (light) hint is out.

Comment: rot13(vf vg eryngrrq gb gur pbzchgref gnt? vg ybbxf yvxr n urk cneg bs n cebtenz)

Comment: @Belhenix rot13(Juvyr n pbzchgre pbhyq or hfrshy va fbyivat gur chmmyr, vg'f cebonoyl abg gur jnl lbh zragvbarq.) Also the `enigmatic-puzzle` tag means it's part of the puzzle to figure out what is involved (:

Comment: Something like rot13(gur tnzr obttyr), in which case the tag might be rot13(jbeq-fdhner be jbeq-frnepu)

Comment: @SamRoy These are not the correct tag.

Comment: dont tell me the missing tag is cipher.

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Don't worry (:

Comment: chess tag? im thinking about rot13(xavtug zbirf)

Comment: @OmegaKrypton A hint is out for this.

Comment: I've found one five-word message, but I'm not sure what exactly to do with it... is that the entire thing? Is the rest of the puzzle irrelevant?

Comment: @Deusovi I'm afraid that's too short (: Also, once you've found the right message, it should be saying quite clearly what you're supposed to do.

Comment: Pretty sure @Deusovi and I have found the same "far" message, but we're not quite sure what the "fast" message is...

Comment: @Skynet_0 There is just one message, which is supposed to be both "far" and "fast".

Comment: Pretty sure I also have the same message.. And actually it's "far" and "fast", in a sense: ROT13(Svaq gjb pryyf juvpu ner frcnengrq gur shegurfg, v.r. gur fubegrfg cngu bs gurfr gjb pryyf vf gur ybatrfg bar.) Therefore, I'm pretty sure the five-word message is the entire thing..

Comment: @Deusovi Ahh... I finally realized you said "five-**word**", which meant "five **words**" whereas I thought about "a five-letter word". Yes, the message is five words, and you can encode any message as your answer (hence the answer is not unique, but it was intended as a way to say "I got the message"). Also, the seemingly irrelevant part of the puzzle is actually necessary to hide the message, which otherwise would be too obvious to find.

Comment: @Skynet_0 I think I misunderstood the comment of Deusovi. See the comment above. Sorry!

Comment: @athin I think I misunderstood the comment of Deusovi. See the comment above. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>  A L o s t E n s
>  b R A a n B . i
>  O m y M B s Q B
>  s L I P P E w l
>  I i s . e N Q e
>  D E N i e D r Y
>  K t h X M E N .
>  C T . R t r a c
> ```
>
> With regards to the hints, "NO, THIS IS NOT ALLOWED!" means that Capital letters are not allowed - they are the walls in your maze.
>  As [found by Deusovi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/91094/63153), the message within your maze is "answer with a similar puzzle". So, I've created a similar puzzle as my answer. The idea of "go as far/fast as you can" is:
>  1.   Find the two points within the maze, which have the longest A* distance between them, with diagonal movement allowed.
>  2.   Trace the A* path, and you have your answer.
>  3.   A* distance is minimizing the distance of a path between two points, so it will opt to skip two straight movements (distance $2$) in favor of a single diagonal movement (distance $\sqrt2\lt2$)
>  4.   On the other hand, you do want to maximize the A* distance, so you will end up with a pretty long path.
>
>  In the similar maze puzzle I designed, the maximum length A* path between two points is as follows:
>
> ```
>  - _ _ _ _ _ _ _
>  _ _ _ a n _ _ _
>  _ m y _ _ s _ _
>  s _ _ _ _ _ w _
>  _ i s _ _ _ _ e
>  _ _ _ i _ _ r _
>  _ t h _ _ _ _ .
>  _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
> ```
>
> Edit: according to later comment by OP, "." is a valid character (isn't a wall in the maze). So, I fixed my answer by replacing a "." with "X". Furthermore, it seems that this allows the following constraint: find the fastest/furthest path that *ends with "."* The original puzzle has a path that ends with ".", equal to "answer with a similar puzzle." Therefore, I have revised my answer to end with "." as well.

Comment: You have almost all clues explained! But there is a small defect: your message actually reads rot13(pneg.vfvfzlnafjre), because... Also, is the path in the original maze unique?

Comment: @WhatsUp Ok, fixed :)

Comment: Actually it was not a constraint, but that certainly makes the sentence look better (: And I guess you haven't noticed the "uniqueness" problem - but the current answer already meets the requirement!

Comment: @WhatsUp rot13(Jryy, grpuavpnyyl gur jbeqf jrer abg gur raq bs gur cngu (fbyhgvba pbhyq'ir orra ybatre), ohg V pbhyqa'g rknpgyl gryy jul gung jbhyq or gur fbyhgvba naq abg tb shegure. V'q ybir na rkcynangvba nf gb jul gung vf, gubhtu.)

Comment: rot13(Bayl pncvgny yrggref ner "jnyyf". Gur gjb yrggref jvgu znkvzny fubegrfg qvfgnapr ner vaqrrq gur "n" ng (7, 8) (7gu ebj, 8gu pbyhza) naq gur "." ng (10, 10), gur fubegrfg qvfgnapr orvat 15\fdeg(2) + 9. Ubjrire gurer ner zhygvcyr fubegrfg cnguf juvpu nggnva gung qvfgnapr. Ohg bayl gur pbeerpg cngu dhnyvsvrf, orpnhfr (lbh'yy frr jura lbh svaq gur bguref).)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at

> only the lowercase letters, a message can be traced.
>
>  [image]
>
>  There are a few 'false paths', but the longest possible message says "answer with a similar puzzle". (No similar puzzles come to mind, but this is apparently everything to be extracted from the puzzle.)

Comment: I'm still not sure what this has to do with "far" or "fast", though...

Comment: You indeed found the message, but haven't got the correct logic (: And that's why rot13(vg vf nfxrq gb perngr n fvzvyne znmr gb qrzbafgengr gung gur ybtvpf ner haqrefgbbq). +1 for finding the message, of course!

Comment: As I commented before, the "far" means the rot13(ybatrfg cngu) whereas the "fast" means the rot13(fubegrfg fgrc). So we need to find the rot13(ybatrfg fubegrfg cngu n.x.n gjb pryyf juvpu ner frcnengrq gur ybatrfg vs jr genprq ol gurve fubegrf cngu). There is no "false paths" IFF you incorporate not the number of letters but rot13(gur qvfgnapr orgjrra gur yrggref v.r. nqwnprag vf bar ohg qvntbany vf fdeg bs gjb).

Comment: @athin Your last sentence is however slightly incorrect (: Are there "false paths"?

Comment: @WhatsUp I read the accepted answer but I didn't see where's the incorrect part of my last sentence (since it did the same thing with accepted answer.) Could you help me to clarify the difference?

Comment: @athin The answer by Avi was accepted because it fulfills the requirement of the question. I added a comment below that answer, explaining some details. More precisely, rot13(gur fubegrfg cngu pbaarpgvat gur gjb yrggref vf abg havdhr), and that's what I meant by "false paths". When you see these "false" ones, you'll find why they are "false" (:

Comment: @WhatsUp Err.. yes.. I also did want to tell that there is no false paths because the same reason. I wrote it that way because Deusovi mentioned about the false paths where actually there won't be any (IFF you incorporated the idea I gave). But anyway ><

Comment: @athin I re-read your comment above, and I think I haven't made it clear that rot13(rira vs lbh zrnfher qvntbany zbir nf fdeg(2), gurer ner fgvyy zhygvcyr fubegrfg cnguf).